Pinning announcements about site changes
This question is specifically motivated by this post, which currently has a net vote count low enough to not appear easily (and which I only found out about by accident) but which is broadly relevant to the community: would it be possible/desirable to, as a general habit, pin meta posts from SE staff which announce recent changes to site functionality?

On the right, in the yellow box, there are posts which have been "Featured".  Note that this one has been in that box over there for a while.  That is as close to "pinning" as is possible.

@XanderHenderson Ah, I didn't see that. Should I delete this post?

On mobile, it's in a box almost at the bottom of the page. (I don't know about others, but I do use mobile most of the time.)
